# Storing variables as local files?

Tags: python-2.7

I am currently setting up a CNN in which most of my debugging time cosist of waiting for the preprocessing step to be done. My input/output data is stored into variables, is it in python (like in R) possible to store the variables as local files, such that I instead keep spending time on generating and structuring my input/output data, just can do this by loading a file?...

My attempt in trying to use pickle:

```
if feature == 0:
            print "Save!"
            input_train = open("input_train_0.pckl",'wb')
            input_test = open("input_test_0.pckl",'wb')
            output_train = open("output_train_0.pckl",'wb')
            output_test = open("output_test_0.pckl",'wb')
            pickle.dump(data_train_input,input_train)
            pickle.dump(data_test_input,input_test)
            pickle.dump(data_train_output,output_train)
            pickle.dump(data_test_output,output_test)
```

Comment: Check out the [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/pickle.html) module.

Comment: I did try pickle but no files were created?